# Dynamic Countdown Clock to Various Dates - Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I've framed this question incorrectly or if it's been asked and answered previously my apologies in advance. My search turned up similar Q&A's which were based around JQuery and/or a static date and I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution with a dynamic date.

```
jsfiddle
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f484126/v6xbwL93/)

The fiddle shows a countdown to a date from the present date, with the output showing the days and hours remaining until the date is met, and then once the "golivedate" has been surpassed it will show that also.

This is partially what I'm looking for however as there's going to be multiple occurrences (100+) with a different countdown date it needs to be dynamic, which in it's current state it's not. I believe that changing to .getElementsByClassName may be the solution to enable me to have multiple occurrences of a class name opposed to being restricted to one instance of .getElementById but I'm unsure quite how to make the switch. I'm also unsure of how to go about being able to add in multiple "golivedates".

Of secondary importance would also be to have some text output next to the date when setting key date markers are met, such as with 1d 23 hours remaining "Going live tomorrow!" and with 23 hours remaining "Going Live Today". Once the Date has been surpassed, "Live Now!" message shown instead of any countdown. 
This may be achieved by var before="Text" var current="Text" but  my expertise is (very!) limited so I'm not sure if this is quite right or how to implement.

In summary I'm asking for assistance to:

- Switch .getElementById to .getElementsByClassName
- "golivedate" to be dynamic, instead of a single occurrence
- Relevant text displayed with X time remaining, and then countdown clock  replaced by text when date has been met.

I release I've written quite a bit here so thanks if you've taken the time to read it - if I've been unclear in anyway please let me know and I'll try to explain further as best as I can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

You can have spans in the following format:

```
<span class="golivedate" data-countdown="Aug 25, 2015"></span>
```

Each span of course can hold a different date or some can have the same. You get all the elements with that class:

```
var glds = document.querySelectorAll('.golivedate');
```

For each element you get the value of its data attribute (i.e. the date):

```
var dt = glds[i].getAttribute('data-countdown');
```

You check whether the date is in the past, if so give it a different text and remove the class:

```
if(seconds_left <= 0) {
    glds[i].innerHTML = "Hurray!"
    glds[i].className = ""
}
```

So overall it'll be:

```
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

setInterval(function () {
    var glds = document.querySelectorAll('span.golivedate');
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();

    for (var i = 0; i < glds.length; i++) {
        var dt = glds[i].getAttribute('data-countdown');
        var seconds_left = (new Date(dt).getTime() - current_date) / 1000;
        if(seconds_left <= 0) {
            glds[i].innerHTML = "Hurray!"
            glds[i].className = ""
        }
        else {
            days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
            hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
            minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
            seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

            glds[i].innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h" + ", " + seconds;
        }
    }

}, 1000);
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/v6xbwL93/6/)

Comment: Thank you - However I am a little confused as to how to add the individual instances of the "golivedate" span in various places, opposed to them all showing at once. Did you also have any thoughts on showing relevant text outlined in my OP?

Comment: Thanks but this has greatly varied from the original criteria. I was looking for various "golivedate" dates with the ability to show said dates individually and not as a group as per your original reply. With this edit it seems to have reverted back to only showing the one static date.

Comment: Alright maybe I misread your first comment I thought you wanted the same countdown to show in different places. So you want different countdowns but just to have them at different places?

Comment: Edited the answer again.

Comment: Thank you Samurai, that's it! Sorry if I confused you before, I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my query and persevering. Do you have any ideas on how to implement the second part of my question, regarding the text. I know you make mention removing the class once a date has elapsed but I'm looking for something more dynamic and that matches the other criteria in my OP.

Comment: Yes something like that! Only I can't quite figure out the date sequence with your example. If we use 20th May 2015 as the day in which something was going live; 20th May = Going Live Today (still showing countdown), 19th May= Going Live Tomorrow (still showing countdown), 21st May: Already Live (no countdown showing)

Comment: Is it fine in any way, but only if it's going live today or tomorrow the countdown should not show?

Comment: It's close but  the days are out of kilter- you have it as May 20th Live Now, and May 21st Going Live Tomorrow! When 21st is after the 20th :) The day and text order need to be as in my last comment if possible. Please note that May 20th is just an example, and it should be true for any date. If it's going live today the countdown should show, so for May 20th countdown would show until May 20th 23:59 has passed it goes to May 21st (the next day). Then it will be Already Live with no countdown showing.

Comment: The dates of course are examples and it'll work for any date, but since today is 20th and no time specified the time is set automatically to 00:00 so the current time is after that and so live now! and 21st is tomorrow so. It only compares the specified date with current date. The part I don't understand is you say you want it to say going live! for 20th, but to say going live tomorrow for 19th? As the past event are happening in the future?

Comment: The reason it says today is because it's less than 24 hours, if that's what you mean, it can be fixed by checking the date instead of remaining days. Just a note though, it's better to check those times with your server, cause clients may have different time zones or even a wrong time set for their computers.

Comment: The 19th going live tomorrow is correct, as the next day would be the 20th where it would go live by the end of the day (May 20th 2015 23:59). May 21st saying going live tomorrow wouldn't make sense, as it's already passed the 20th. May 21st would be "Already Live". Regarding the time zone can we use GMT?

Comment: Today is may 20th (well it might be different in different time zones, but GMT). 21st is 2 day after 19th, how can 19th go live tomorrow while 21st is already live? 21st hasn't past yet but 19th has. Numbers go like 18-19-20-21-22 ,  probably I just don't understand what you're saying though.

Comment: The messaging is informative relevant to the go live date of 20th. 18= live in two days time; 19 = go live tomorrow; 20th= live today; 21st=already live;22nd=live two days ago.

Comment: I understand where we got our wires crossed; in your example you were using each day independently from the date I was using as an example (May 20th). I should have spotted that sooner, sorry. If we use May 22nd 23:59 as the go live time, would it be possible to have this set of messaging: May 21st = "Going Live Tomorrow" May 22nd = "Going Live Today" May 23rd = "Already Live". It's important that on May 22nd until it actually changes to the 23rd May GMT that it keeps the "Going Live Today" message.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/v6xbwL93/9/ I added `live_date = ("May 22 2015 23:59");` if you want the current date instead, just remove `live_date` from `var cd = new Date(live_date);` ... and so we're clear, changing the day "we use" to 22nd 23:59 doesn't make any difference, either I don't understand it or it doesn't make sense whatsoever to me.

Comment: Thanks Samurai this is brilliant - what I meant by "if we use May 22nd 23:59 as the go live time" is previously you stated the date was set automatically to 00:00 hence why as soon as the day began the message "Live Now" was being shown. I tweaked the statements slightly as when `live_date` was removed incorrect messaging was being shown for some dates. This seems to have rectified it http://jsfiddle.net/f484126/v6xbwL93/10/ Thanks so much for your time and patience and my apologies for confusion caused by myself!